# Markdown not recognizing characters in URLs

Tags: support, markdown

I just came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773540/should-one-use-php-to-print-all-of-a-pages-html/1773565#1773565), which included a note that the URL they tried to use wasn't being recognized by the markdown engine.

I tried swapping the hyphens for `%2D` and suddenly the URL was recognized. When I clicked the link to confirm it worked properly, I noticed Wikipedia was performing a redirect from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller gets redirected to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller.

The difference is subtle, but the "proper" Wikipedia URL uses an ndash instead of a hyphen. As you can see from the links above, this is a breaking character for Markdown URLs.

I know that in this case switching with hyphens works, but should Markdown be updated to allow this character (and probably the mdash as well, for good measure - any others?) in case there are situations where it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (or click the toolbar hyperlink button)
2. paste URL
3. press <kbd>enter</kbd>

result:

```
[Model-View-Controller on Wikipedia][1]

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
```

Comment: To be fair, this auto-encoding wasn't available in November of 2009 when the original post was made.

Comment: Firefox has been my main browser for six years, yet I've never noticed this. Seems to only work when you paste the whole URL, not when you just replace a portion like I was doing last night. Thanks Lord President Atwood.

Comment: @jesse I prefer Galactic President Superstar McAwesomeville http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5RQNBFKK30

Comment: Duly noted, though I took Lord President from Doctor Who, which is clearly superior to (the non-NPH parts of) HIMYM.