# "$" is silently removed from links used in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

I was trying to post something similar over on Super User:

```
… [images](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowExternalImages)?
```

However, the comment was rendered as:

```
<a href="http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:wgAllowExternalImages">...</a>
```

The `$` was stripped without further notice, and if I hadn't checked, I wouldn't have seen that the link was broken. [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) says that this is a valid URL character. Therefore, please allow it.

Comment: Trying to [reproduce](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowExternalImages). (See the broken link?)

Comment: trying workarounds - 1) posting the link as-is: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowExternalImages and 2) posting as code `http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowExternalImages`. Test result: workarounds available

Comment: @gnat Interesting. My workaround was to URL-shorten it :P

Comment: What about [percent-escapes?](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgAllowExternalImages) Works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be working after the next build.

See [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/url-filter-goes-rogue-on-unicode-characters-in-urls/128824#128824) for details.

Answer (score 5):

**If possible, `$` should not be removed but just left alone.**

See the comments on my answer and check out [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125613/145350), it appears that this character *is* valid.

--

**If not possible, `$` should be replaced by `%24`.**

In practice, this would not break the link (at least for `http` links).

This replacement might not be that comform to the standard, but at least it works better...

Comment: I upvoted this before realizing that, actually, this advice technically violates the URI spec ([RFC 3986 section 2.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2)), which explicitly says that `$` (and the other "reserved" characters)  are allowed in URIs _and_ may not be percent-encoded without potentially changing the meaning of the URI.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: However, later RFCs can amend earlier RFCs. And I don't see how *potentially changing the meaning* is happening here, because you still end up at the same resource...

Comment: They can, but I'm not aware of any that would, in this case. (In particular, AFAICT, RFC 3987 doesn't; it uses the exact same set of "reserved" characters with the same meaning.) As for potentially changing the meaning, the point is that `$` and `%24` are not equivalent in URIs (or IRIs): there could be URI schemes that use `$` as a delimiter, like e.g. `&` is used as one in HTTP query strings. Yes, in practice, replacing `$` with `%24` is unlikely to break anything, at least if only applied to `http` URIs, but it's still technically the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Posting this to contrast with the other answers:*

> **The `$` character should be allowed in links, and should not be mangled in any way.**

According to [RFC 3986, section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), all of the following "reserved" characters are allowed in URIs:

```
gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

The reason these characters are called "reserved" is that they may be used as delimeters between URI components or subcomponents (as e.g. `&` is used to delimit parameters in `http` URI query strings), and thus are not generally considered equivalent to their percent-encoded forms.

I do realize that not all of these characters can or should always be treated as part of an adjacent URL by the StackExchange parser, since some of them are either used as delimiters in Markdown syntax, or are common punctuation characters that are frequently appended to URLs included in English text.  However, `$` does not seem to fall into either of these categories, and thus there should be no reason not to just treat it as a normal valid URL character.

In particular, parsing `$` as part of an URL but then stripping it out completely, as the OP describes as happening in comments, is **just plain broken.**  *Whatever* you do, **don't do that.**

Ps. The same set of reserved characters is also allowed in IRIs by [RFC 3987, section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-2.2).

Answer (score 1):

This should **not** be allowed without consideration for [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987)

The W3C is actively promoting the switch to IRI's which have syntactic restrictions based on the [Universal Character Set](http://std.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC2/WG2/) which covers things like currency

**ADDITIONAL EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**

I am not going to copy the spec, but the important sections are [2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-2.2), [4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-4.1) and [6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-6.1)

It also cites [RFC 3491](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3491) for "unwise" characters

Comment: What are these syntactic restrictions, exactly?

Comment: -1, I don't see `$` in any of the tables listed for unwise characters in appendix C of RFC3454, nor any reference to it in 2.2, 4.1, or sections 6.1 of RFC3987...

Comment: The point was that you should be considering this in relation to the IRI RFC and not the URI RFC. I take it when you read the "unwise" characters you specifically qualified them against RFC3454 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3454.txt)

Comment: @WilliamGreenly: I'm saying I find no reference to currency or `$` (nor its code-point) in any of the RFCs you've referenced.

Comment: Also, can you please summarize in one sentence what you *want*? "This should not be allowed" in the sense of not allowing `$` to appear? It's a URL I want to post. It shows in my browser's URL bar, why shouldn't I be able to link it? Well, I can, but it gets silently stripped, which produces a broken link. That's the bug here.

Comment: -1 for lack of clarity. If you just literally mean that RFC 3987 should be kept in mind when writing URL parsers, then, yes, that's of course true. However, if you're implying that something in that RFC, or any of the others it cites, somehow forbids or advises against the use of `$` in the path portion of URIs / IRIs, could you _please_ explain exactly where and how you think it says so?

Comment: In fact, the only mention of `$` I can find in RFC 3987 is in section 2.2, in the BNF grammar fragment marked as "same as those in [RFC3986]", which includes `$` in the `sub-delims` production, whose characters are explicitly _allowed_ in the path portion of IRIs. (See the `ipath-*`, `isegment-*` and `ipchar` productions above.)