# Can markdown mini replace an en dash with a normal hyphen in URLs?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, hyperlinks, markdown

Further to Tim Stone's response to my [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127752/so-eliminates-hyphen-from-url-when-linking) regarding what turned out to be an en dash in an URL: Would it be reasonable for markdown mini to replace en dashes with normal hyphens? Or is that Wikipedia article's URL just a fluke?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would be a problem often encountered.

Comment: I seem to remember it being a pretty wide-spread problem with Wikipedia URLs once upon a time, but I don't know if it's still prevalent. That aside, doing the replace shouldn't be too difficult, and this might be a special case worth handling if only for the fact that the two characters are somewhat hard to distinguish in the edit box unless they're side-by-side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that would be just wrong. We have, however, [changed the handling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128824/115866) of not-whitelisted characters in those URLs from "just remove" to "percent-encode", which obviously solves your original problem as well (and [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118924/is-silently-removed-from-links-used-in-comments)), while *not* changing the URL – on Wikipedia, different dash kinds may be equivalent, but this probably is not the case everywhere.

Comment: You and your common sense, bah! Although Wikipedia is the only place I can ever remember seeing dashes in URLs before anyway (and I've seen the entire internet, or something), this is indeed a much saner solution.

Comment: So I can assume [this "bug"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118924/159624) will be fixed as well, any time soon?

Comment: @slhck Notice that I gave that very post as an example. Edit: Oops, I wanted to. I pasted the wrong link. Fixed. The answer is yes.

Comment: Ah, this is welcome change indeed!