# SO eliminates hyphen from URL when linking

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

I tried to link to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm` in a comment and when I click on the link, SO changes the URL to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FisherYates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm`.

It's a comment in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9965803/76810

Comment: The more important question is were exactly did you get that link from?

Comment: You'd better warn them or I'll send Tim Stone ;)

Comment: I got the link by right-clicking the "2 The Modern Algorithm" link at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle and selecting "Copy Link". I'm running Safari 5.1.4 under OS X 10.6.8. I got the link in this comment by copying the URL from Safari's address bar.

Comment: **RE: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]:** If this is [to be percent-encoded in markdown mini](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127755/134300), shouldn't it also be percent-encoded in full markdown? It seems backwards for markdown mini to be more featureful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because it's not a hyphen, it's an [en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). Replace it with a normal hyphen and both Stack Overflow and Wikipedia [will be happy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

In normal post Markdown, the link simply won't be rendered, but in Markdown Mini (as used by comments), the sanitization method is to remove invalid characters in the URL before rendering.

Answer (score 2):

This will be working after the next build.

See [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/url-filter-goes-rogue-on-unicode-characters-in-urls/128824#128824) for details.