# Comment with a link with whitespaces

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I'm not able to format a link with whitespaces in it in comments correctly.
See my comment: [Grails understanding belongsTo Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132329/grails-understanding-belongsto-association/11132607#comment14591231_11132607)

```
[hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain Classes/hasOne.html)
```

will not work properly (the same output only *connected link* is linked).

Comment: What website gives out links that have unencoded spaces in them? That's just wrong on so many levels...

Comment: testing. [hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html)

Comment: Just manually replace space with `%20` and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: [hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html)

The trick is to urlencode the space by hand:

```
[hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html)
```

... also works for those annoying Wikipedia links with parentheses.

Comment: Is it imaginable to autodetect whitespaces in those links and enrich them with `%20`? As a feature request?

Comment: @matcauthon [Probably not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128824/162704).

Comment: @matcauthon: Whitespaces are used for the `[text](URL "title")` syntax, so auto-encoding it is not an option.