# Non-Latin characters in URLs are not accepted

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, usability, localization

I can't seem to find a way to link to pages containing non-Latin characters in URLs.

For example, **Tåg.info** (with an å). The å is required, since tag.info is a completely different website.

Using the normal link mechanism (Ctrl+L) doesn't allow me to publish the post, I receive a message

```
Your post contains the invalid external link http://t%C3%A5g.info. Please correct it.
```

I can't even paste the URL directly in the text either. Very frustrating.

---

My browsers don't have an issue with this escaped URL though (Firefox 18 and Chrome version-of-the-day).

I've seen [this other related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/url-filter-goes-rogue-on-unicode-characters-in-urls), but this doesn't work either:

```
 [Tåg.info](http://tåg.info)
```

As a workaround, I can use the [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) version

```
[Tåg.info](http://xn--tg-yia.info/)
```

however Firefox does the conversion to and from Punycode transparently, so there's no easy way to generate this URL, and obviously it's not very user-friendly. Chrome doesn't, though, so internationalized URLs result in Punycode.

In case it's important, this is for a post  on [Travel-SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com), and links to non-English websites are not uncommon.

Comment: From the question you linked: *"This is comment-only at the moment. There's nothing inherently problematic with doing the same thing in posts (i.e. questions and answers), and we may do it at some point..."* - So, this would be more of a [meta-tag:feature-request] since, according to that post, it's not *supposed* to work like that (unless that's just out-of-date).

Comment: @animuson: I kind of see where you are coming from, but for me this is a clear bug: "I can't include a valid URL that my browser understands perfectly in a SE post." The reason why is irrelevant -- IDNs have been around for some years now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using the normal link mechanism (Ctrl+L) doesn't allow me to publish the post, I receive a message
>
> ```
> Your post contains the invalid external link http://t%C3%A5g.info. Please correct it.
> ```

That part is where the bug is (the rest of the behavior is intentional). There was a typo in the link validator that would only accept this URL if the domain's *first* character is non-ASCII as well.

Fixed in the next build.