# URLs not being parsed & linked correctly in comments

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

[This comment I posted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/dynamically-change-schema-to-accommodate-custom-fields#comment109430_60702) shows the URL parsing bug I just encountered. It's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: The parser appears to have stopped at an n-dash. I remember some time ago extended ASCII characters in URLs were encoded, and shown, as %-sequences in browsers' address lines. They show normally now but maybe that's just a browser feature, maybe the standard still requires the address to consist of 7-bit chars only?

Comment: URL Encoding is still required for some characters like %20 for a space, but I'm guessing this is unrelated and is an issue with whatever regex or parsing the site is doing in the comments.

Comment: I would usually post URLs using `[text](url)` markdown, e.g. [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model). Of course this drastically reduces the amount of text you can put in a comment (maybe that's by design :-)). Anyway I think this affects the whole network, not just dba.se...

Comment: or his one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/url-filter-goes-rogue-on-unicode-characters-in-urls/128824#128824