# How can I insert a link containing parentheses?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

This link below contains `(` and `)` which totally confuses the link system on SO.

`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects(double, double, double, double)`

Attempts to use it:

[standard link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects(double, double, double, double))

[end of text link][1]

I think it is an absolutely awful link with spaces, brackets and all, but it is valid nonetheless. There should be a way to create a working link to a specific method in javadoc.

---

faulty link below

[1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects(double, double, double, double)

Comment: Do you know about the Ctrl-L or Command-L keyboard shortcut? That works fine for me.

Comment: *Sigh*, Oracle documentation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, this is not a valid URL. Spaces are not a valid character in URLs and must be [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as `%20` (or `+`, under classical rules).

The Stack Exchange markdown engine applies heuristics to determine the end of a URL; it allows some characters to go unencoded, including balanced parentheses and commas, but doesn't go as far as to allow spaces. I don't think the engine should change to accommodate spaces.

This is arguably the job of your browser. When I copy the URL from the Firefox URL bar to the clipboard, Firefox helpfully copies it as

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29
```

Chrome, on the other hand, copies

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects(double, double, double, double)
```

to the clipboard. You have to either encode the URL manually, or use the hyperlink editor tool (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or click on the corresponding button in the editor toolbar). This tool performs the necessary conversion (it escapes all special characters).

Comment: The version with `+` signs only "works" in the sense of going to the right page, but not in the sense of going to the right anchor _on_ the page. At least, that's the behavior on Firefox and Chromium. The version with `%20` works right on both.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You're right, `+` isn't supported here. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Ps. The `+` encoding is a special convention for [HTML form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4), and is only valid in the query segment of the URL (and technically only if the application being queried is expecting form data). The [standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) way to encode a space, which works in all parts of a URL, is `%20`.

Answer (score 3):

Properly encoding the URL would make it work. As stated in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83901/220538) by Jeff, you can do the following:

- Select the anchor text
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- Paste the URL

The markdown editor will do all  the necessary encoding for you and it will produce a valid link.

[Example link to Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29)